# Bicentric Quadrilateral Pyramid Problem

Tags: geometry, circles

The original problem is this:

> The base $ABCD$ of a pyramid $ABCDM$ is inscribed in a circle,
> $AB = 9$, $BC = 10$ and $\angle ABC = 60^\circ$.
> Find the altitude of the pyramid if
> all dihedral angles at the base are equal to $60^\circ$.

I understand that $\angle ADC = 120^\circ$ (sum of opposite angles equal to $180^\circ$) and that because the dihedral angles are equal a **circle can be inscribed as well**, making it a **Bicentric Quadrilateral**, but this is as far as my knowledge goes.

I could also find $AC$ if I want, but I don't see how that helps us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $AD=x$ then $CD=x+1$ and:
$$
AC^2=9^2+10^2-2\cdot10\cdot9\cos60°=x^2+(x+1)^2-2x(x+1)\cos120°.
$$